# JavaScript: How to check if multiple libraries contained in a single source has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shared-libraries, arcgis-js-api

I am faced with a `multipleDefine` error when my external JavaScript library(which loads multiple other external libraries) clashes with `<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/"></script>`. I have tried moving the Esri script to the bottom most part of the code while my external library stays on top and it didn't work as it takes awhile to load.

Is there a way that would allow me to check if the multiple libraries under my external library has loaded before I start loading the Esri script?

Note: The Esri script is not required to be loaded immediately, it could be as late as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `load` event(which ensures all your `external files` are loaded) and add your `Esri script` dynamically, once all external files are loaded.

See - https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded

> load – not only HTML is loaded, but also all the external resources:
>   images, styles etc.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/";
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
});
```